# add missing date and missing item vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help to setup this vba.
I'm looking to add a cell with the date is missing and driver. 
for example.

```
10/29/2018  Name    Item    driver
10/30/2018  Name    Item    driver
(add missing date here, no available , no available and driver)
11/02/2018  Name    Item    driver
```

if the date is missing and the driver is also missing to add it in.

[image: Please see pic]

I hope this helps.

Comment: What is the missing date? In the row below 10/30/2018 should it be the date: 2018-10-31?

Comment: Another option is to create a new sheet with all dates (using fill method) and then use a vlookup to fill in the ones who exist.

Comment: yes 10-31-2018.

Comment: is it an empty row or is there no space in between?

Comment: @Brotato I don't have a empty row in between or space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below assumes that the values starts at A2 and that all the relevant data is stored in order eg.column B-D. This will insert a row and fill in the data so that every date has an entry. If you have a lot of data to process it might be worthwhile to add in the usual `Application.calculation=xlmanual` and `application.screenupdating = false` to speed it up. Just be sure to reset them back to their default states when you're done

```
Option Explicit
Sub datefiller()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastdate As Long
    Dim startDate As Long
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    i = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        While Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            If Not .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1 Then
                .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1
                .Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Value = "N/A"
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "driver"
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: Adding in the driver's name and accounting for different groupings

```
Option Explicit
Sub datefiller()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastdate As Long
    Dim startDate As Long
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    i = 3

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        While Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            If (Not .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1) And .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i - 1).Value Then
                .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1
                .Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Value = "N/A"
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i - 1).Value
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(. the code doesn't do anything. If you look at the pic I posted the excel sheet is sort by driver and date. between the 2 dates is missing one to add the date to the missing one.

Comment: Can you delete the rows that have the words (add missing date) and just have the values next to each other?

Comment: The macro assumes that each row 2 and beyond will have a date

Comment: It didn't work. the excel sheet keeps adding numbers and it crash my excel.

Comment: yes I did. my excel also has more numbers. I delete them to try your code and that's when I my excel crash.

Comment: I've made some changes to the last block of code. I tried it with a table matching your sample data and it worked for me. I put the first line of data with the driver name John in Row 2 and it ran

Comment: now the code works thanks but I have couple of problems. The first (A2) driver it's not adding the date that is missing.
can the code be adjusted to not pass the last date in the excel? for example if the last date in the excel is 11/01/2018 not to add 11/02/2018?
I'm sorry for the trouble and thank you for all your help.

Comment: The macro ***fills*** in the missing dates between two that are set on the worksheet. You can probably get what you want more easily by creating an entry below the singular entry that contains the end date you want

Comment: Thank you Brotato.

Comment: @Brotato, really impressive. I started but gave up when I saw that you need account for missing dates... Good work :)!!!